# How to pass page number on button click in api Url in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, rest, pagination, fetch

When I send a get request to an API with a specific page number I am able to get all the data on that particular page. Now I want to implement the previous and next button functionality so that I can get data on the basis of a user action. In other words, I want to send incremented page number in the API URL.

Here is my code.

Thanks in advance.

This is my js code

```
function fetchData(){
    let url = '/api/job/list?'
    let pagenumber = 800
    fetch(`${url}&page=${pagenumber}`)
    .then(response =>{
        if(!response.ok){
            throw Error('ERROR');
        }
    
        return response.json(); 
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.job_list);
        const html = data.job_list.map(user => {
            return `
            <tbody  id="JobList">
                <tr>
                <td>${user.sno}</td>
                <td>${user.company}</td>
                <td>${user.title}</td>
                <td>${user.created_at}</td>
                <td>${user.expiration_date}</td>
                <td>${user.is_expired}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="${user.job_link}">
                        <div style="
                            white-space: nowrap; 
                            overflow: hidden;
                            text-overflow: ellipsis"
                        >
                            ${user.job_link}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>${user.location}</td>
                </tr>                               
            </tbody>
            `
        }).join("");
        // console.log(html)
        document.querySelector('#JobList').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin' , html);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}

fetchData();
```

This is the Html code

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="tablehead">
    <tr class="tablerow">
        <th>Sno</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Created At</th>
        <th>Expiration Date</th>
        <th>Is Expired</th>
        <th>Job_link</th>
        <th>location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="JobList" class="tableBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say,

1. give an id to two different buttons `next` and `back`
2. add an onclick function to the buttons, with the fetch function with the values `this.id`
3. in the fetch function make an if statement that looks for they ids
4. at last increment/decrement the page value with `++` and `--`